# Hibernate 4.3.11, Postgres 9.3, Spring 4.3.0 JSON Custom Data Type

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, postgresql, plpgsql

I can not figure out how can I pass a **json** to a **postgres function** and get **json** as result with **Hibernate 4.3.11, Postgres 9.3, Spring 4.3.0**. When I am trying to pass **json** it taking it as a **character varying**.

**JSON** is not a built in data type in **Hibernate** I know that, but I have searched almost 3 days to accomplish this thing, but can not come to a solution. What ever I got they telling create a custom data type but I can not build a custom data type also.

Please any one having step by step solution will help me lot.

Comment: You will have to add a layer which takes your json, converts it to java objects for hibernate. And the same for the other way round. spring mvc however will do that for you.

Comment: Do you have any working example, so that I can follow those steps. If so please give me, will help me lots.

Comment: you could have a look at my tutorial here: http://www.digitalwright.net/2015/12/11/developing-a-web-api-with-spring-and-accessing-it-with-angular-js-part-1/ 
But I must admit that it may not be the best tutorial available. but I'm sure you can fin dothers if required

Comment: By doing what you have said in the title... Use a custom type... You will need a converter/usertype to do this. This is needed to explain hibernate to use what SQL type for that specific column and how do the conversion from/to that datatype.

Comment: Jackson will do the serialization for You, so from JSON input you will get DTO object in Java. Then just rewrite it to Entity DAO and use with hibernate the way you want.